# View with select union all vs View with converted union into UDF - performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am currently maintaining a database with at least 10 legacy applications using it. It's actually a long story to tell so I will not go into details about it.

In the database, we have a view with this code:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_ViewControl]
AS
SELECT
    'CAX1' AS table_name,
    max(convert(datetime,txn_pDate)) AS curr_dt,
    (
        SELECT MAX(CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate)) 
        FROM tbl_txn WITH(NOLOCK)
            WHERE CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate) <
            (
                SELECT MAX(CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate)) 
                FROM tbl_txn WITH(NOLOCK))
    ) AS prev_dt,
    MAX(DateCreated) AS final_updte
FROM tbl_txn WITH(NOLOCK) UNION ALL

SELECT
    'CAX2' AS table_name,
    max(convert(datetime,txn_pDate)) AS curr_dt,
    (
        SELECT MAX(CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate)) 
        FROM tbl_txn WITH(NOLOCK)
            WHERE CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate) <
            (
                SELECT MAX(CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate)) 
                FROM tbl_txn WITH(NOLOCK))
    ) AS prev_dt,
    MAX(DateCreated) AS final_updte
FROM tbl_txn WITH(NOLOCK) UNION ALL

SELECT
    'CAX3' AS table_name,
    max(convert(datetime,txn_pDate)) AS curr_dt,
    (
        SELECT MAX(CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate)) 
        FROM tbl_txn WITH(NOLOCK)
            WHERE CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate) <
            (
                SELECT MAX(CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate)) 
                FROM tbl_txn WITH(NOLOCK))
    ) AS prev_dt,
    MAX(DateCreated) AS final_updte
FROM tbl_txn WITH(NOLOCK) UNION ALL

SELECT
    'CAX4' AS table_name,
    max(convert(datetime,txn_pDate)) AS curr_dt,
    (
        SELECT MAX(CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate)) 
        FROM tbl_txn WITH(NOLOCK)
            WHERE CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate) <
            (
                SELECT MAX(CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate)) 
                FROM tbl_txn WITH(NOLOCK))
    ) AS prev_dt,
    MAX(DateCreated) AS final_updte
FROM tbl_txn WITH(NOLOCK)
```

To improve the performance, I replaced the code with this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_vw_ViewControl()
RETURNS @M_Control TABLE 
(
    table_name varchar(15) not null,
    curr_dt datetime not null,
    prev_dt datetime not null,
    final_updte datetime not null
)
AS
BEGIN

    declare
        @curr_dt datetime,
        @prev_dt datetime,
        @final_updte datetime


    SELECT
        @curr_dt = max(convert(datetime,txn_pDate)),
        @final_updte = MAX(DateCreated)
    FROM
        tbl_txn WITH(NOLOCK)


    SELECT @prev_dt = MAX(CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate)) 
    FROM
        tbl_txn WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE
        CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate) < @curr_dt

    INSERT @M_Control VALUES( 'ACCOUNT', @curr_dt, @prev_dt, @final_updte )
    INSERT @M_Control VALUES( 'CARDHLDR', @curr_dt, @prev_dt, @final_updte )
    INSERT @M_Control VALUES( 'CUSTOMER', @curr_dt, @prev_dt, @final_updte )
    INSERT @M_Control VALUES( 'TRANSACTNS', @curr_dt, @prev_dt, @final_updte )

    RETURN
END
GO

--================== ALTER VIEW

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_ViewControl]
    AS
SELECT 
    xControl.table_name
    , xControl.curr_dt 
    , xControl.prev_dt 
    , xControl.final_updte
FROM
    dbo.udf_vw_ViewControl() xControl

GO
```

The original view when used in the application runs for about 4-5 mins. The updated view using the UDF is unexpectedly much slower running for atleast 15 mins. I was expecting that the updated view would be faster as I have already removed the redundant part of the query.

Any Idea why? Or is there another approach that would be much faster?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

From the first view I see potensial performance issue:

```
CONVERT(datetime,txn_pDate) < @curr_dt
```

Because of `convert` index is not used even if it exists.
Can you provide execution plan for generating another ideas?

Comment: The original view has the same where clause in each select statement. So why is the performance of the updated view is slower? Sorry, can't give you the execution plan, i intensionally change the table name and the fields for security reasons. ;-)

Comment: I don't see any `where` clause in  original view. You just select it - yes, but this is not the same.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. :) The `where` clause is actually in the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Vladimir is on the money there I would add a calculated column and index on that

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_txn ADD txn_pDate_Date AS 
    CASE WHEN ISDATE(txn_pDate) = 1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, txn_pDate) ELSE NULL END
```

You can then index the calculated column

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_tbl_txn_txn_pDate_Date ON dbo.tbl_txn (txn_pDate_Date)
```

Then update the original view to reference the calculated column and, if all relevant information is included in the question, you should see an improvement

Comment: Thanks Clint. :-) Putting an index is actually obvious. I just don't understand why is the updated view is slower than the original.

Comment: I was answering the part of your question "Or is there another approach that would be much faster?"